# Get rid of "producer" and "consumer" tags

Tags: discussion, tags

The definition of the "producer" tag: "an actor in the Producer Consumer scenario". The "consumer" tag does not have a definition.

I really see no reason why these tags should not be merged into the "producer-consumer" tag. There is no case where you would be talking about a producer or consumer and not be talking about the Producer-Consumer problem.

Comment: What?  There is no "producer-consumer problem."  There are only producers, consumers and their associated queues.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem

Comment: That has a different meaning from Producers and Consumers.